# Visual Studio Code Blank Spaces on Sides of Coding Region

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

After I had to do a hard reboot on my mac this gap appeared in VSCode.  It's like the coding region is narrower.  The coding region is now centered and there are blank gaps on either side.  Any idea how to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try: view - toggle center layout. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZLur.jpg)

Comment: Geez, that's it.  I swear I looked through every setting multiple times but somehow missed that one.  Been coding too long today.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)